# The probability of my guessing a coin toss is 1 in 4

Tags: probability

Suppose I’m asked to guess heads or tails when you toss a coin. Suppose I decide to select head or tails by conducting a coin toss of my own. There is a 1 in 2 chance that my coin toss comes up heads. There is a 1 in 2 chance of your coin toss coming up heads. There is a 1 in 4 chance of the two coin tosses coming up with the same result. Why then is my actual chance of correctly predicting your coin toss 1 in 2?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$. There are four different outcomes, when you consider the two coins.

Comment: "There is a 1 in 4 chance of the two coin tosses coming up with the same result..." That is not true. The probability on equal outcomes is 1/2.

Comment: The odds of my coin toss being heads = 1/2, the odds of your coin toss being heads = 1/2. My understanding is that to get the probability of both events happening, we multiply 1/2 x 1/2 = 1/4.

Comment: Your calculation gives the probability of correctly predicting H on my coin. But what about correctly predicting T on my coin? Your question seems to be asking for the probability of predicting H or T correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 possibilities:

- You toss a $H$

  - Other toss is a $H$ - you are correct.
  - Other toss is a $T$ - you are wrong.
- You toss a $T$

  - Other toss is a $H$ - you are wrong.
  - Other toss is a $T$ - you are correct.

Each of the 4 cases is equally likely. In two of them you predict correctly and in the other two you predict incorrectly.

Thus the probability of you being correct is $\dfrac 24 = \dfrac 12$.